# Como agrego un header de autorizacion a un query usando flutter_graphql?

Tags: flutter, graphql

estoy utilizando la dependencia de flutter_graphql pero hasta el momento no se como añadir el token que guardo en shared preference ya que debos obtenerlo a partir de una variable con un await utilizando getInstance(). Esta es la configuracion que utilizo para el cliente:

```
import 'package:graphql_flutter/graphql_flutter.dart';


class GraphQLConfig {
 
  static HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink('http://servidor:3000/graphql');
  GraphQLClient clientToQuery() => GraphQLClient(link: httpLink, cache: GraphQLCache());
}
```

y este es el servicio donde uso el cliente:

```
class ProductService {
  static GraphQLConfig graphQLConfig = GraphQLConfig();
  GraphQLClient client = graphQLConfig.clientToQuery();

  Future<List<Product>> getProducts() async {
   
    try{
      QueryResult result = await client.query(QueryOptions(
        fetchPolicy: FetchPolicy.noCache,
        document: gql('query de consulta'),
        variables: const {
      "variables"
    },
        ),
        );
        if(result.hasException){
                throw Exception(result.exception);
        }
        List? res = result.data?['findProductsByName']['data'];

        if (res == null || res.isEmpty) {
          return [];
        }

        List<Product> products = res.map((product) => Product.fromMap(map: product)).toList();
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print(products);
        }
        return products;
    }catch (e){
      throw Exception(e);
    }
    
  }
}
```

Como deberia agregar mi bearer token si necesito antes crear variables como estas:

```
 final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = prefs.getString('token');
```

Answer (score 0):

podrias crear una instancia de tu graphql algo asi y llamas tu archivo en client. espero te ayude

```
 final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
  'tu_url_de_api_aqui',
   defaultHeaders: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer tu_token_de_autorizacion_aqui',
 },
);
```